How to style siblings on hover in CSS?
I am trying to apply a CSS color change on the siblings of a list of links under the following format:
<ul>
  {{ range .Pages }}
    <h2>
       <a class="item" href="{{ .RelPermalink }}">{{ .LinkTitle }}</a>
    </h2>
  {{ end }}
</ul>


As I am working on Hugo, the list of links is the index of files in the folder, in this example there is a folder with 4 articles. In this case, I range over the pages of the folder (ie the 4 articles) which ends up being something like this:


.list-items a:hover.item:not(:hover) {
  color: lightgray;
}

.item {
  color: black;
  transition: color 0.3s ease;
}
<ul class="list-items">
  <h2>
    <a class="item" href="article1">Article1 Title</a>
  </h2>
  <h2>
    <a class="item" href="article2">Article2 Title</a>
  </h2>
  <h2>
    <a class="item" href="article3">Article3 Title</a>
  </h2>
  <h2>
    <a class="item" href="article4">Article4 Title</a>
  </h2>
</ul>



More articles will be added in the future, so the goal is to have all the links in black by default and when hovering, the one being hovered remains black while all the siblings color changes to lightgray.
I unfortunately haven't been able to apply the desired effect with the following CSS:
.item {
  color: black;
  transition: color 0.3s ease;
}

.list-items a:hover.item:not(:hover) {
  color: lightgray;
}

I have tried the following code:
.item {
  color: black;
  transition: color 0.3s ease;
}

.list-item a:hover.item:not(:hover) {
  color: lightgray;
}

and:
.item {
  color: black;
  transition: color 0.3s ease;
}

.list-item:hover.item:not(:hover) {
  color: lightgray;
}

Any clue what I'm missing?
Thanks!

a:hover.item:not(:hover) makes no sense. An element can not be hovered, and also not hovered, at the same time. "Any clue what I'm missing?" - a proper [mre] of the issue to begin with. Right now, I can't even tell what your "a list of links under the following format" actually means. Do you have multiple of those h2 containing one link each, or one h2 containing multiple links?

My apologies for lacking in the description and thank you for your time and help. I have edited my post for more clarity. I have tried to add a parent container in the form of the  and have tried to aim for the a links.

FYI: ul can't have headlines as children, you need to insert li first. (And then probably leave out the h2, because these are not really headlines to begin with.)

"and when hovering, the one being hovered remains black while all the siblings color changes to lightgray" - .list-items:hover .item { color: lightgray; } to change the color of all items, when the container gets hovered, and .list-items .item:hover { color: black; } to re-set it to black for the specific link that is hovered.

That worked nicely, thank you very much! If you want to post the answer as an answer so I can select it as the answer and mark this solved, otherwise I'll copy paste your comment in order to do this.


and when hovering, the one being hovered remains black while all the siblings color changes to lightgray

.list-items:hover .item { color: lightgray; } to change the color of all items, when the container gets hovered, and .list-items .item:hover { color: black; } to re-set it to black for the specific link that is hovered.

Here I replaced the <h2> with proper <li> since nesting the h2 in the ul is invalid.  I then adjusted the CSS to have the same style as the H2 and fixed the hover syntax in the CSS.


.list-items a:hover {
  color: lightgray;
}

.item {
  color: black;
  transition: color 0.3s ease;
}

.list-header {
  display: block;
  font-size: 1.5em;
  margin-top: 0.83em;
  margin-bottom: 0.83em;
  margin-left: 0;
  margin-right: 0;
  font-weight: bold;
}
<ul class="list-items">
  <li class="list-header">
    <a class="item" href="article1">Article1 Title</a>
  </li>
  <li class="list-header">
    <a class="item" href="article2">Article2 Title</a>
  </li>
  <li class="list-header">
    <a class="item" href="article3">Article3 Title</a>
  </li>
  <li class="list-header">
    <a class="item" href="article4">Article4 Title</a>
  </li>
</ul>



